# Invoke-Webrequest | Invoke-RestMethod - Powershell question marks instead of hebrew

Tags: json, powershell, hebrew, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

I'm trying to send a post with Invoke-Webrequest / Invoke-restmethod in 2 scenarios. one of them is working well and the other is working but replacing Hebrew letters with question marks...

**This one is working well:**

```
json = @{
 
    "contactID"= "my id";
    "text" = "היי";
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:8880/messages/send/text -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $json
```

**This one is replacing Hebrew chars with question marks:**

```
  $json = @"
{
      "contactID" : "$($LastMessage.key.remoteJid)",
      "quotedMessage": {
          "key": {
              "remoteJid": "$($LastMessage.participant)", 
              "id": "c" 
          },
          "message": { "conversation": "$($LastMessage.message.conversation)" } 
      },
      "text": "היי" 
  }
"@
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:8880/messages/send/text -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $json
```

Any option to use the second one without braking the Hebrew letters?
Tried several ways to convert it to UTF8, but it doesn't help at all, just making the question marks with black background behind.

I will appreciate any help.